# Tuleap REST API behind proxy

Tags: rest, proxy, tuleap

I am trying to do a REST call to the Tuleap REST API.

The issue I'm having is that I am behind a proxy and it seems like the API does not support the keyword CONNECT.

See image there:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENRCb.png

We see here that with curl the result I'm having is 405 Method Not Allowed.

Is there a way that I can work around this? I've been searching but couldn't find an answer so far.

Comment: You are right, CONNECT is not allowed by Tuleap API. But I don't understand why there is one here (disclaimer, I'm not a proxy expert).

Comment: I believe since Tuleap API is only accessible with https (at least myversion is that way) the proxy has to establish a HTTP Tunnel to the server which requires a CONNECT.